# Android : Auto Pull from web database when screen wakes

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, pull-to-refresh, android-wake-lock

I have an android application which pulls the device state from a web-server . Currently am trying to auto-sync to the database to get the updates to my android .

Here are the following things I thought I can use :

1. Having a refresh button which user can click and get the details again from the database .
2. Pull-to-refresh method seems decent too .

However apart from those traditional manual approaches I am trying to find another way where user can have auto-sync without manually doing any refresh or pull on the screen .

In my current app , if the user is not interacting with the app screen , the screen currently goes dim , technically I guess it goes to sleep .

I am trying to find a way if I can call the same refresh task or pull the data from the database , when he tries to wake up the application screen , since that is the only time the user will be more interested to see the device and their updated states .

Is it something I can achieve ? Is it possible to do this by running and aysnc task in `onResume()` or am I missing out something ?

My current code for that activity lies in a `CardView`

item_device.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="3dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/device_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/device_name_set"
            android:textSize="35sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_operating_temp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/device_name"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/temp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/device_temperature"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Temperature set to 10° celsius"
                android:textSize="15sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_mac_address"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_operating_temp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/mac" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/device_status"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/pon_stop"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/layout_mac_address"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="0.9">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/device_power"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/power_on" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/device_start"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/start_on"
                    android:text="@string/start_off" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/device_set_temperature"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:src="@drawable/temperature" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use **`services`** , its exactly designed for that. here's a good tutorial to get you started http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html
and here's the android docs for services.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: Thanks for looking into this , The info you gave was useful , but it might not suit my case . The trouble is if I make it run as a service , the service should detect an event like through a notification or something so that the service can be triggered and do the desire work . The reason I was relying on wake up or something was so that something can tell my app to now sync and pull details from database .

Comment: There is something called sticky service look into that also